# Delete Record From Javascript Array Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

i have a java script array object and i want to delete items from a specific index in that object, i have a comma separated string of  that indexes. problem is that when i delete it using `splice` array indexes got changed, and other indexes's object not got deleted.

```
    var DeletedConditions="3, 5, 19, 50";

    for (var k = 0; k < DeletedConditions.split(", ").length; k++) {
         ConditionObject.splice(DeletedConditions.split(", ")[k], 1);
    }
```

`DeletedConditions` string can be anything.

please help me out. how to get this done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I suggest you officially turn the indexes into a formal array. Having a string as an index reference, you are prone to missing a split shall there be a case where the values are not separated by `,`

Then [the code](http://jsfiddle.net/xDYp9/1/):

```
var content = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'bam', 'dom', 'zok'],
    deleteIndexes = [5, 1, 3],//should delete zok, bar, bam
    i;

//sort from least to greatest: [1, 3, 5]
deleteIndexes.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
});

//we loop backwards (performance enhancement)
//now we loop from greatest to least
//we now splice from greatest to least 
//to avoid altering the indexes of the content as we splice
for (i = deleteIndexes.length; i-- > 0;) {
    content.splice(deleteIndexes[i],1);
}

console.log(content); //["foo", "baz", "dom"]
```

​

Comment: Going backwards may not help performance (in certain versions of Opera it was much slower than forwards, in other browsers it often makes no difference). But going backwards is handy if looping and splicing, otherwise each time you splice a member you have to `--i` and `--len` as it moves the members.

Comment: @RobG not that it is a performance improvement on all browsers, I just got used to looping backwards when direction is irrelevant. It also provides shorter code. Splicing does require backwards looping though.

Answer (score 1):

You can always decrement the k iterator after splicing inside the loop:

```
k--;
```

Comment: If you remove N elements of an array in a loop then you have to decrement the loop variable N times.

Comment: @rahul because only the items after the current one get their index shifted

Answer (score 1):

```
var DeletedConditions="3, 5, 19, 50";
var list = DeletedConditions.split(", ")
for (var k = 0; k < list.length; k++) {
    // using splice here   
    list.splice(k,1); 
     k--;
}

console.log(list.join(', '))
```

Comment: i think you got it wrong i don't want to delete it from DeletedConditions. i have a separate object want to delete from that on given index in DeleteConditions

Comment: @rahul: Am explaining here..how could we solve array indexed problem

Answer (score 1):

Removing an item from the beginning of the array shuffles the later elements up and changes their indices, as you've observed. But if you go through the list of items to remove *backwards* then it will remove the later elements first so the indices will still be correct for the elements closer to the beginning of the array.

Also, *please* don't do the `.split()` operation on every loop iteration - the inefficiency might not make much difference on a string with four numbers in it, but it makes the code kind of messy and on principle it is just kind of yucky.

```
var DeletedConditions="3, 5, 19, 50",
    delCondArr = DeletedConditions.split();

for (var k = delCondArr.length - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
     ConditionObject.splice(delCondArr[k], 1);
}
```

If there's a possibility that the `DeletedConditions` strig might not be ordered just add a `.sort()` after you split it:

```
delCondArr = DeletedConditions.split().sort(function(a,b){return a-b;});
```

...in which case you don't need to loop backwards.

Comment: Tidier still with a while loop: `var k = delCondArr.length; while (k--) {...}`. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It might be easiest to copy the original array, omitting the deleted items in the process. Something like this would do the trick...

```
var DeletedConditions="3, 5, 19, 50";
DeletedConditions = DeletedConditions.split(', ');
var newConditionObject = [];
for(var k = 0; k < ConditionObject.length; ++k) {
  if(DeletedConditions.indexOf(k) !== -1) { continue; }
  newConditionObject.push(ConditionObject[k]);
}

// result is in `newConditionObject`
console.log(newConditionObject);
```

Comment: This will certainly work, but may I suggest inverting the `if` condition to do `if(...indexOf(k) === -1) { ...push(...); }` (instead of having `continue`)? To my eye that would be just a little more straightforward.

Comment: It would seem that "straightforward-ness" is in the eye of the beholder.  Of course, there's nothing wrong with your suggestion, but I prefer the approach I've shown above.  Either one will work just fine.

Answer (score -1):

```
var fruits = new Array("apple", "banana", "grapes", "oranges","mosambi","aaa","bbb","ccc"); 

var DeletedConditions="1,3,4,5";

var indexArray = new Array;

indexArray = DeletedConditions.split(",");

for (var i = 0; i < indexArray.length; i++) {

   fruits.splice(indexArray[i], 1);
}
```

Comment: Isn't this just a more efficient version of the incorrect code from the question? (Though you've introduced your own inefficiency by declaring `indexArray` as a `new Array` and then immediately setting it equal to another array.) It still doesn't deal with the problem of the indices changing in the array being spliced...